# Selecting radio buttons to make text appear

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

Using radio buttons displayed on a panel, is it possible to select the radio button and then display some text on the panel explaining what the user has selected?

So here is a list of radio buttons

```
    public void RadioButtons() {
    btLdap = new JRadioButton ("Ldap");
    btLdap.setBounds(60,85,100,20);
    panelHolder.add(btLdap);

    btKerbegos = new JRadioButton ("Kerbegos");
    btKerbegos.setBounds(60,115,100,20);
    panelHolder.add(btKerbegos);

    btSpnego =new JRadioButton("Spnego");
    btSpnego.setBounds(60,145,100,20);
    panelHolder.add(btSpnego);

    btSaml2 = new JRadioButton("Saml2");
    btSaml2.setBounds(60,175,100,20);
    panelHolder.add(btSaml2);
}
```

User selects btLdap

```
btLdap.setSelected(true);
```

Now how do you make the text appear on the panel not a message box

Comment: Your method names shouldnt start with a capital letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display a text when a radio button is selected you could use `ActionListener`.

```
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
add(textArea);

JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton();
add(radioButton);
radioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        textArea.setText("Selected");
    }
});

JRadioButton radioButton2 = new JRadioButton();
add(radioButton2);
radioButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        textArea.setText("Selected 2");
    }
});

radioButton.setSelected(true);
```

When the first is selected it will change the text of the JTextArea with `The first is selected!`, same the second radio button but with `The second is selected`.

As you said, `radioButton.setSelected(true);` `setSelected` is used to select/deselect a radio button.

In this example i used textArea, but you can use everything which have a method to change the text it contains (an image too!)

Official DOC, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

---

Anyway, `actionPerformed` is not called when `setSelected` is used so i would go to something like a method

```
private void updateText(int index)
{
    String text = null;

    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            text = "Selected";
            break;
        case 1:
            text = "Selected 2";
            break;
    }

    textArea.setText(text);
}
```

And then call `updateText(0 or 1 etc.)` when you want to select `setSelected` another radio button and update the text too.

All this is useful, if you want to show a "what happens if you press it" message, but if you just want to change the text of the area with the text of the radio button, just use

```
textArea.setText(e.getActionCommand());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Example how to use an `ActionListener` on a `JRadioButton`:

```
public class ListenerExample extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JRadioButton check = new JRadioButton("hello");
private JLabel label = new JLabel();

public ListenerExample() {
    check.addActionListener(this);

    add(check);
    add(label);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(800, 600);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ListenerExample();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof JRadioButton) {
        JRadioButton button = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
        label.setText(String.valueOf(check.isSelected()));
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an anonymous inner class you will have something like:

```
yourRadioButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) {

        // here you will write the code that you want to
        // be executed when your radio is clicked
        yourLabel.setText( "Some text..." );


        // if you want to exeute it onlye when it is selected
        // you will need to do this
        if ( yourRadioButton.isSelected() ) {
            // some code here
        }

    }
});
```

In Java 8, recently released, you can use a lambda expression to register your listener. Something like:

```
yourRadioButton.addActionListener( event -> {

    // here you will write the code that you want to
    // be executed when your radio is clicked
    yourLabel.setText( "Some text..." );


    // if you want to exeute it onlye when it is selected
    // you will need to do this
    if ( yourRadioButton.isSelected() ) {
        // some code here
    }

});
```